# If statements aren't working in p5.js. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Basically, I am using Google's Teachable Machine for something, and I am making a p5.js webpage to go around the data. I have some if statements for a timer because I want to only be changing it if it has been a few seconds (note that I haven't implemented that yet, so that won't work yet even if the code starts to work). I have `console.log()` statements to help with things, and I am using booleans to help with my if statements just in case that helps for some reason (neither does, but I know doing `console.log(myBool)` returns the value being `true` when it should be, but the if statements still don't work. Anyways, enough rambling. Here is my code:

```
<div>
  Teachable Machine Audio Model - p5.js and ml5.js
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.3/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Global variable to store the classifier
let classifier;

// Label
let label = 'listening...';

// Teachable Machine model URL:
let soundModel = 'https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/khgwJCtEk/';


function preload() {
  // Load the model
  classifier = ml5.soundClassifier(soundModel + 'model.json');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(320, 240);
  // Start classifying
  // The sound model will continuously listen to the microphone
  classifier.classify(gotResult);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  // Draw the label in the canvas
  fill(255);
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(label, width / 2, height / 2);
}

let firstTime = true;

// The model recognizing a sound will trigger this event
function gotResult(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  // The results are in an array ordered by confidence.
  console.log(results[0]);
  console.log(results[0]["confidence"]);
  var startTimer = results[0]["confidence"] > 0.8 && firstTime == true;
  var continueTimer = results[0]["confidence"] > 0.8 && firstTime == false;
  var newThing = results[0]["label"] != label;
  
  if (startTimer == true) {
    var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
    label = results[0].label;
    firstTime = false;
    console.log("First time!")
  }
  else if (continueTimer == true) {
    if (newThing == false) {
      console.log("Not first.")
      var newTimeout = 1000 - milliseconds;
      this.timeoutVariable = setTimeout((function(thisObj) { return   function() { thisObj.update(); } })(this), newTimeout);
      console.log(newTimeout);
    }
    else if (newThing == true) {
      label = results[0].label;
      firstTime = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Any idea why my if statements aren't working? If it is a silly problem, sorry, silly problems happen often for me.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I got an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: now is not define
```

It turns out when you do:

```
var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
```

in one of your if statements, you are using an undefined `now`. You can try adding a definition of `now` before that line:

```
var now = new Date();
var milliseconds = now.getMilliseconds();
```

This should fix the error, and the code should start to work (although other problems may still occur).